# if statement checking for multiple boolean conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a if statement that must call function checkEmpty() for every conditions.

```
function checkFormFilled(evt){
    var isFilled;
    if(checkEmpty('id1', 'class1') && //condition 1
       checkEmpty('id2', 'class2') && //condition 2
       checkEmpty('id3', 'class3') && //condition 3
       checkEmpty('id4', 'class4')){ //condition 4
       evt.preventDefault();
       isFilled = true;
    }
    return isFilled;
}
```

The problem is when the condition 1 is false(any preceding condition is false), skips to the  evt.preventDefault() line, doesn't get call other following checkEmpty() functions.

I want to call evt.preventDefault() when all conditions return true.

Is there other way around to make this work?

Comment: that's exactly what you are doing, what is the problem ?

Comment: when first condition 1 is false, it skips to evt.preventDefault() line. I need to call all four conditions before calling evt.preventDefault() line.

Comment: that's because the AND operator close after the first false. you need a OR operator.

Comment: @haeminish this could be optimized even more! What are the `..`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir it's just a string.

Comment: 'when first condition 1 is false, it skips to evt.preventDefault() line.'  - this cannot be true. It should not call evt.preventDefault().

Comment: @haeminish are they following that pattern `id1`, `id2`... or that was just as an example?

Comment: So, you should not encounter problem. you are doing the right way

Comment: Do you have access to `checkEmpty`'s definition? I'm wondering if its negated before returning !

Comment: checkEmpty() return true if empty and return false if filled

Comment: Can you post the code of `checkEmpty`?

Comment: What I need is check(call) all conditions from 1-4 and return false if any of them returned false.

Answer (score 4):

try the logical operator `||` which is OR

Answer (score 2):

```js
function checkEmpty(val){ return val;}
function _conditioncheck(e){
    if(checkEmpty(false) && checkEmpty(true) && checkEmpty(true) && checkEmpty(true)){ 
 console.log('true....');
 e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="click" value="Click ME" onclick="_conditioncheck(event);" />
```

Its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If at least one of the conditions is False, it will not go inside the IF block. For multiple && statements, once a FALSE is received, all other succeeding && statements are not checked anymore and FALSE is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Its called short-circuit.

1- In a condition check composed of &&, if the first element evaluates to false, all of the remaining conditions are ignored, returning false for the whole condition.

2- In a condition check composed of ||, if the first element evaluates to true, all of the remaining conditions are ignored, returning true for the whole condition.

---

He edited the question. this is no more true. I'm making it community wiki, here to stay.

Best workaround to this is using `||` or re-ordering sequence of sub-conditions in your condition-check to let other elements get tested whenever you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you

> must call function checkEmpty() for every conditions.

And

> I want to call evt.preventDefault() when all conditions return true.

If you are sure that `checkEmpty()` returns a boolean, you could use the [bitwise and (`&`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dazfy1f3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) operator:

```
function checkEmpty(x) {
  console.log('checkEmpty called for ' + x);

  return false;
}
if(checkEmpty('..1', '....') & //condition 1
   checkEmpty('..2', '....') & //condition 2
   checkEmpty('..3', '....') & //condition 3
   checkEmpty('..4', '....')){ //condition 4
  console.log('inside if');
}
```

Output:

```
checkEmpty called for ..1
checkEmpty called for ..2
checkEmpty called for ..3
checkEmpty called for ..4
```

See [fiddle **demo** here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/7afL26v0/2/).

Comment: Note: if `checkEmpty()` may return something other than `true` or `false`, don't use `&` as it is a bitwise operator. Example: `1 & 10` returns `0`, which is not what you would expect if it were a logical operator (since `truthy && truthy` is `true`).

Comment: OTOH, if you don't know if `checkEmpty()` always returns a boolean, you can double negate them: `if(!!checkEmpty('..1', '....') & !!checkEmpty('..2', '....') ...` (notice the addition of `!!` before every `checkEmpty()` call).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of objects, you could try the `every` function.

Example

```js
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  array.push({
    id: i, bool: true
  });
}

function check(item)
{
  return item.bool == true || false;
}

if (array.every(check))
{
  console.log("all true");
}
else
{
  console.log("return false instead");
}



// Just an example of something that is false
array[1].bool = false;

if (!array.every(check))
{
  console.log("something is false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now with the chained `&&` operators  is saying if all of these things are true then `event.preventDefault`. If you really need to check every one of the conditions and proceed if any are true then you should use the logical `OR` operator `||` instead.